# GWT "super dev mode" eclipse debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt-super-dev-mode

Is it possible to debug in IDE for both server and client with Super Dev Mode?  I'm fed up with switching back and forth, I love the classic way for debugging.
In a debug session you feel like you are in heaven no matter what Client or Server all under the same hood and your control.  I really miss that, any chance in future to get back that luxury. I'm stuck  with Firefox 24 and Old method....

cannot use the advantages of Super Dev Mode.

Any plug-in, work around, hack or feedback would be appreciated.

This is a big issue for GWT users and i see that lots of developers are quitting GWT becuase of this. I already passed the point of no return and suffering a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for eclipse at http://sdbg.github.io/ which you might want to try out.
I installed it but don't use it currently, because it opens a new Chrome where I'm not logged in to the Google Account.

Comment: I tried, it works but not really like the classic debug session it's a work around but pretty much useless..